# Many to many and how to get a queryset from queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have following models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=30)

class Store(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=30)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
```

How to get `Store`s with product named `product_name` and also, get all the products (except the product with name `product_name`) ? Is it possible to make it in one query?
In raw SQL it would be simple `JOIN`s. Not sure how to implement it via Django.

Comment: Field `product` should be renamed in `products` because you can store many products in it.

Answer (score 26):

You can actually do these things with Django due to it's lazy queryset evaluation. Django's `in` field lookup accepts both lists and querysets. The following will create a nested SQL code:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(store_set__in=stores_qs)
stores_qs = Store.objects.filter(product__name='product_name')
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) are the Django `in` docs.

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to filter the stores based on an attribute of Product, and then prefetch_related of the retrieved objects.

```
Store.objects.filter(product__name="product_name").prefetch_related('product')
```

This should hit the database the fewest times to achieve what you are looking for - twice.

Further documentation can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

Comment: This won't exclude the "product_name" products from the prefetch_related result

Answer (score 2):

Get Stores with product named "product_name" :

```
Store.objects.filter(product__name='product_name')
```

Get all the products except the product with name "product_name":

```
Product.objects.exclude(name='product_name')
```