# Django prefetch_related From Model With Multiple ManyToMany Relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say I have a few models in Django:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bars = models.ManyToManyField(Bar)
    bazs = models.ManyToManyField(Baz)

class Bar(models.Model):
    quxs = models.ManyToManyField(Qux)
```

I can use prefetch_related to get all Bars belonging to Foo and all Quxs belonging to Bar with:

```
Foo.objects.prefetch_related('bars__quxs')
```

But how can I use prefetch_related to get this information as well as all the Bazs belonging to Foo?  Would something like:

```
Foo.objects.prefetch_related('bars__quxs', 'bazs')
```

work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. You can pass in multiple lookups to `.prefetch_related()`

Comment: so this: Foo.objects.prefetch_related('bars__quxs', 'bazs')

Comment: yes, that is correct. Is that not working for you? I know as long as `bars` and `bazs` are many to many fields on Foo that should work.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is how to access `Foo.bars.quxs` now.  Normally, it's just `Foo.bazs.all()`, but I can't access the `quxs` through `Foo.bars.all().quxs.all()`.

Comment: I think I've found my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916642/many-to-many-and-how-to-get-a-queryset-from-queryset).  Is that the only way to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to filter on the `Foo.bars.quxs` or just access it once you have it? To access quxs, first grab one of the bars, then access's its quxs. For example: `foo_object.bars.all()[0].quxs.all()` that will access all the quxs for the first bar in foo_object.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to filter on it, so what I ended up doing was `Qux.objects.filter(bars__in=Foo.bars.all()).all()`.  I think this should get me what I need right?

Comment: First of all, you can't actually call `Foo.bars.all()` unless `Foo` is an instance of `Foo`. Secondly, since `Qux` is on the other side of the many to many relation with `Bar`, if you're filtering from `Qux` you need to filter with `bar_set`. For example: `Qux.ojects.filter(bar_set__in=foo_object.bars.all()).all()`