# Filtering django M2M field options with queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

I want to filter the options that appear in a M2M field of a form using a queryset. I have read that `limit_choices_to` can only be used with ForeignKey. Is there something similar to `limit_choices_to` that can be applied to M2M?

This is my model:

```
class Inspection(models.Model):

    ref         = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tools       = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True,blank=True)
    areas       = models.ManyToManyField('specimens.Area',null=True,blank=True)
```

And this is the model of the M2M field:

```
class Area(models.Model):

    ref         = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    specimen    = models.ForeignKey(Specimen)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['ref','specimen']
```

I would want to filter inspection_areas with a queryset: 
`Area.objects.filter(specimen="specimen")`

Other post ([Many to many and how to get a queryset from queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916642/many-to-many-and-how-to-get-a-queryset-from-queryset)) explains a way to do this, changing the admin form I think (I don't understand it so much), but this does not work for me, getting `DoesNotExist` errors or `Super` errors. Do I have to change my `InspectionForm` for the `InspectionAdminForm` that says the post before?

[image]

Any ideas?

EDIT-1:

I have realized that it throws other different error:

[image]

This is the complete code I have used:

```
class InspectionAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Inspection

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InspectionAdminForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['areas'].queryset = Area.objects.filter(specimen=self.instance.specimen)



class InspectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = InspectionAdminForm
    filter_horizontal = ['areas']
```

Comment: Did you perform `makemigrations` and `migrate` after setting up your models? It looks like it does not know where to put your data (nor fetch it from)...

Comment: You're right. I forgot to migrate. Solved the latest error. I don't have any errors now, but the queryset filter only works in my Admin view, while in my form I still view all the Area options without filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had set some initial parameters to my Inspection modelForm, I set:

```
inspectionform = InspectionForm(None, initial={'specimen':specimen})
```

I also change the `__init__` method of the InspectionForm:

```
class InspectionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Inspection

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InspectionForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['areas'].queryset = Area.objects.filter(specimen=kwargs['initial']['specimen'].id)
```

And that's all! Now it works great.